# How to add a service while creating a Linux image

Tags: linux, service, systemd, buildroot

I want to add my service (simple C++ app) to Linux image.
I know how to add service in console while Linux is running (with help of systemctl) but I need to make Linux image with already added service, so when Linux starts my service have been already run, how can i do it?
I make Linux image in buildroot, if its important.

Comment: Create the `.service` file and add symlinks from an appropriate directory, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/my.service`

Comment: Yep its work,. Add service to /usr/lib/systemd/system and make symlink in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

Answer (score 1):

For a package `foo`, you can set `FOO_INSTALL_INIT_SYSTEMD`. If the service file contains the appropriate `WantedBy` stanza, it will be enabled automatically.